# How do I correctly use the List(Of T).Contains Method?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, list

I am struggling trying to figure out how to search a List(Of Checkbox) for a specific checkbox name. I would like to search an existing list, and add checkboxes that match a specific name to another list. In the existing list, I added checkboxes with names such as: chkClass11, chkClass12, chkClass21, etc.

My code is as follows:

```
Dim lstCheckboxes As New List(Of CheckBox)
Dim lstGroupCheckboxes As New List(Of CheckBox)

Do While intNextGroupNumber <= intTotalGroups
    Dim grpNewGroupBox = New GroupBox
    grpNewGroupBox.Name = "grpGroup" & intNextGroupNumber
    grpNewGroupBox.Text = "Group " & intNextGroupNumber
    grpNewGroupBox.Location = New Point(intCurrentXPosition, intCurrentYPosition)
    grpNewGroupBox.Size = New Size(intGroupBoxWidth, intGroupBoxHeight)
    grpNewGroupBox.AutoSize = True
    strGroupBoxNameAddArray(intArrayLocation) = "grpGroup" & intNextGroupNumber

    Do While intCurrentRow < intTotalRows
        Dim chkClassCheckBox = New CheckBox
        chkClassCheckBox.Name = "chkClass" & intNextGroupNumber & intCurrentRow
        chkClassCheckBox.Text = m_DataTableClass.Rows(intCurrentRow).Item("ClassName")
        chkClassCheckBox.Location = New Point(intCurrentXPosition, intCurrentCBYPosition)
        grpNewGroupBox.Controls.Add(chkClassCheckBox)
        lstCheckboxes.Add(chkClassCheckBox)
        intCurrentCBYPosition += 30
        intCurrentRow += 1
        intArrayLength += 1
    Loop

    Me.Controls.Add(grpNewGroupBox)

    strGroupNamesArray(1, intNextGroupNumber - 1) = grpNewGroupBox.Name ' Add group names to array to sort checked checkboxes into

    intCurrentRow = 0
    intNextGroupNumber += 1
    intCurrentGroupBoxHeight = grpNewGroupBox.Height
    intCurrentYPosition = intCurrentYPosition + intCurrentGroupBoxHeight + 50
    intCurrentCBYPosition = 15
    intArrayLocation += 1
Loop

intArrayLocation = 0

'Search strGroupBoxNameArray for next group and then insert strGroupBoxNameAddArray values
For Each Group In strGroupBoxNameAddArray
    intClassNumber = 1
    Try
        strGroupName = strGroupBoxNameAddArray(intArrayLocation)
        intGroupNumber = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(strGroupName, 1)

        If Not dicGroups.ContainsKey(Group) Then
            Do
                Try
                    strCheckBoxName = "chkClass" & intGroupNumber & intClassNumber
                    If lstCheckboxes.Contains(strCheckBoxName) Then
                        lstGroupCheckboxes.Add(lstCheckboxes.Item("chkClass" & intGroupNumber & intClassNumber))
                    Else
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                    intClassNumber += 1
                Catch
                    MessageBox.Show(ErrorToString)
                    Exit Do
                End Try
            Loop
            dicGroups.Add(Group, lstGroupCheckboxes)
        End If
        intArrayLocation += 1
    Catch
        MessageBox.Show(ErrorToString)
        Exit For
    End Try
Next
```

Is there any good reference material on lists? I am having a difficult time finding material that explains exactly how a list works.

Thanks!

I did replace the following:

```
Do
    Try
        strCheckBoxName = "chkClass" & intGroupNumber & intClassNumber
        If lstCheckboxes.Contains(strCheckBoxName) Then
            lstGroupCheckboxes.Add(lstCheckboxes.Item("chkClass" & intGroupNumber & intClassNumber))
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
        intClassNumber += 1
    Catch
        MessageBox.Show(ErrorToString)
        Exit Do
    End Try
Loop
```

With the following:

```
lstGroupCheckboxes.AddRange(lstCheckboxes.Where(Function(cb) cb.Name.StartsWith("chkClass" & intGroupNumber)))
```

But I am having some trouble with the line:

```
dicGroups.Add(Group, lstGroupCheckboxes)
```

I did not have an issue filling this dictionary key with the list lstCheckboxes, I just have an issue filling it with the new list lstGroupCheckboxes. Is there something wrong with the format of the new list?

Comment: Would it be possible to show us the declaration of lstCheckboxes?

Comment: What version of .net are you using? And why not use linq?

Comment: I have added the declaration code that you have requested. I am not quite sure how to use linq. I am using VB 2010.

Comment: You know that hungarian notation is no longer recommended, right? Microsoft's own style guidelines (where hungarian was invented) no explicitly recommend _against_ using it.

Comment: I did not know that I was one of the few that use Hungarian notation. I think it just makes it easier to remember the variable type later on in the code. Why is it not recommended?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.Net List.Find. Pass values to predicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655793/vb-net-list-find-pass-values-to-predicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .Where() or .Any() instead of .Contains(). This entire If block:

```
If lstCheckboxes.Contains(strCheckBoxName) Then
```

(the entire block, not just that line) can become:

```
lstGroupCheckboxes.AddRange(lstCheckboxes.Where(Function(cb) cb.Name = strCheckBoxName))
```

---

Replace the entire Do ... Loop with this:

```
lstGroupCheckboxes.AddRange(lstCheckboxes.Where(Function(cb) cb.Name.StartsWith("chkClass" & intGroupNumber))
```

Comment: This code will leave me in an infinite loop if I remove that entire block. How can I exit my Do...Loop when lstCheckboxes does not contain a checkbox with the name strCheckBoxName?

Comment: You have an infinite loop because your loop has no condition. The Exit Do code is kind of a weird way to write that. I recommend removing the loop entirely, and modifying the code I posted to allow any Class Number. Edit coming momentarily that shows this.

Comment: Got it. It makes more sense now. I really am struggling finding info on lists. Do you know anywhere I can find more info about this?

Answer (score 0):

This will create a list of all the checkboxes that match:

```
lstCheckboxes.Where(function(x) x.Name=="chkClass" & intGroupNumber & intClassNumber).ToList()
```

Comment: I was not able to get this to work. It gave me the following error: "Overload Resolution Failed because no accessible 'Where' can be called with these arguments"